# How to hide a div that doesn't have an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to write a piece of code (I am thinking of JavaScript/jQuery) that would hide the two divs highlighted. The problem is that they do not have IDs and they belong to classes but are not the only objects in those classes. So I cannot hide the classes, because that will hide more things that I want. The "parent" div has an ID.

Please find the code here: [image]

Is there any way I can reference the divs that I want to hide by the order number from the parent? Any other solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code here as well

Comment: Please post the actual HTML markup and what makes these `div`s unique

Comment: are there more divs with same class name in that parent div?

Comment: @Mritunjay *they belong to classes but are not the only objects in those classes.*

Comment: please describe any specific features of the divs you want to modify vs the ones you want to leave untouched

Comment: Any of the proposed solutions (which try to find things by position) is going to be brittle and will break with minor changes to the markup (which is a bad attribute to have).  I'd suggest you either fix the markup to put appropriate identifiers in it or write code to actually find the desired content so it's not so brittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the table's ids to identify the container.

```
$("#RoleListTB").closest(".hlrl").hide();
```

`closest()` is looking up the DOM to the next matching parent, so you can start at your table as shown.

i've made a fiddle for this:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle" >show/hide</a>
<div>
    <div class="hlrl">
        <span id="RoleListTB">
            RoleList Table
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

$("#toggle").click(function(){
    $("#RoleListTB").closest(".hlrl").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NGVQ3/

Comment: Looks pretty much like the same thing in my answer.

Comment: Lol, at least it is the same. Your answer didn't show up when i postet my one xD

Answer (score 2):

As I see that those elements are sub child of an element with an id of `#view` so you can make use of `nth-` selectors or you can use jQuery `:eq()`

```
$("#view > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(2), 
   #view > div:nth-of-type(4) > div:nth-of-type(1)").hide()
```

Or using CSS *(Recommended)*

```
#view > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(2), 
#view > div:nth-of-type(4) > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

---

Here, the first selector i.e `#view > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(2)` selects a third `div` element which is a direct child to an element having an id of `#view` and further it selects a direct `div` element which is a second child of that type

Second selector i.e `#view > div:nth-of-type(4) > div:nth-of-type(1)` selects fourth direct `div` child element to an element having an id of `#view` and further, it selects first direct child `div`

Comment: I'm not a fan of coding CSS or JS by position as relatively minor changes to the markup (such as just adding another row somewhere) can break your code and better code is not that fragile.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can't help it :) anyways the DOM looks weird to me, so the code is evil on its own

Comment: Can't help what?  I offered a solution that doesn't use hard coded positions.  Besides evil HTML doesn't mean you have to use an evil solution to deal with it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I provided the best we can do with CSS, so in a way, answer is not wrong..

Comment: I didn't say your answer was wrong, just that I'm not a fan of this technique.  The OP said jQuery was fine so there's no requirement that this has to be done in CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me If there is no other sibling with same class name.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">

    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="hideDivs()">Hide</button>
```

Javascript

```
function hideDivs() {
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('parent');
    var childDivs = parentDiv.getElementsByClassName('child');
    for (var i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++) {
        childDivs[i].style.display = "none";
    };
}
```

Comment: Except in the OP's HTML, there are other siblings with the same class name "h111" so I don't see how this works for the OP's HTML.  Also, not sure why more code in plain javascript is being used when jQuery is available that offers relevant higher level functions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of coding by position (e.g. the 3rd or 4th element) because relatively minor changes to the markup such as just adding a new div for spacing can break code that relies on specific hard-coded positions.

If you want something that won't break when there are changes to the markup that might change the relative position of items, then you have to look for more specific content that you want to hide.  There are many different ways to do this depending upon what you know about the content and what is the best marker to indicate that you have the right div.

Here's one way that looks for unique identifiers in the content you want to hide, then goes up to the proper parent to hide that content:

```
$("#RoleListTB").closet(".h1r1").hide();
$("#AccessProfileListTB").closest(".h111").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this by using a CSS pseudo-selector in your query.

```
$('#view').find('div.h1r1:nth-of-type(2)')
```

or you could just be more specific

```
.h111+.h1r1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that their positions are fixed and that won't change, then you could use `nth-child` selector.

Something like this:

```
$("#view").children("div:nth-child(3)").children("div:nth-child(2)").hide();
$("#view").children("div:nth-child(4)").children("div:nth-child(1)").hide();
```

Or, just:

```
$("#view > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2)").hide();
$("#view > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1)").hide();
```

Alternatively, using `.eq`:

```
$("#view").children("div").eq(2).children("div").eq(1).hide();
$("#view").children("div").eq(3).children("div").eq(0).hide();
```

*Note*: `.eq` is zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) Jquery selector to search by index:

```
$( ".some:gt(0)" );
```

0 - is first .some

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector to select an element at a particular index.

Assume the parent div has an id `parent`
it had child `div's` having the class `sub`.

so if you want to hide the second child element

```
$("#parent .sub:eq(1)").hide();
```

since the child ordering starts with `0' index

Answer (score 0):

Divs can have more than one class . . .

```
<div class="h111">
```

changed to

```
<div class="h111 hideDiv">
```

CSS

```
.hideDiv {display: none;}
```

then use javascript to show it when you want it to be shown :)

Answer (score 0):

Your div contains the tables which have a ID. So you can use

$('#yourTableIDHere').parent().hide();

This code will hide your div.